# how to find generic list values by index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Generic List that it contains 4 value .
how can I get my generic list values by index ? I want to get all values in generic list 
this is my code :

```
var Checked = (form.GetValues("assignChkBx")).ToList();     
string str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Checked.Count; i++)
{
    str = str + Checked[i]. +",";
}
```

in this code I got all checkboxes values that checked . Now I want to get all values . how can I get values ?

Comment: "get all values" - *what* values are you talking about?

Comment: I get rows ID when a checkbox checked .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question about the generic list is very misleading and I suspect that it has nothing to do with your real problem.

Depending on how you generated the checkboxes inside your view that might be possible or not. If you hardcoded them using directly an `<input type="checkbox">` tag values of checkboxes that were not checked will never be sent to the server - that's how HTML checkboxes work. In this case you will not be able to get all values. If on the other hand you used the `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper to generate them then you will notice that this helper adds a hidden field to each checkbox in order to send all values. This helper operates on boolean values though.

So I would recommend you creating a view model that will contain 2 properties: one holding the values you are interested in and one boolean property indicating whether the user selected this value or not in the view:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a view model which has collection of those items:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now inside your view you can render those values like this:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for ( var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Items[i].Checked)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Items[i].Value)
        </div>
    }

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally inside the controller action that this form will be submitted to you will be able to get all values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    foreach (var item in model.Items)
    {
        // here you could use item.Checked and item.Value
    }
    ...
}
```